# MATLAB: How do I evaluate a symbolic function given an array of numbers, and return an array of results?

Tags: matlab

My code looks like this in MATLAB:

```
nn = 0:50;
syms n z X H Y
X = 1/(1+1/z);
H = (2+2/z)/(1-0.8/z);
Y = X*H;
x = iztrans(X,z,n);
y = iztrans(Y,z,n);
xx = subs(X, n, nn);
yy = subs(Y, n, nn);
```

However, I got this error:

```
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input
expression into a double array.
If the input expression contains a symbolic variable,
use the VPA function instead.
```

What is the correct way so it will return a whole array of numbers based on nn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matlabFunction` is your friend! It's a really useful function, I'd recommend looking at the documentation too so you can apply it in other situations. It converts a symbolic expression into an anonymous function that does element-wise operations so you can input matrices.

```
nn = 0:50;
syms n z X H Y
X = 1/(1+1/z);
H = (2+2/z)/(1-0.8/z);
Y = X*H;
x = iztrans(X,z,n);
y = iztrans(Y,z,n);
Xfunc=matlabFunction(X);
Yfunc=matlabFunction(Y);
xx=Xfunc(nn)
yy=Yfunc(nn)
```

Comment: matlabFunction for the win! +1